# Sending Form Data to Email PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a form that sends the information to the admin when it gets submitted. However, nothing happens. I've checked my junk/spam mail and still nothing. I also set `$admin_email = ""` to the correct email address. Any ideas?

**PHP**

```
      //Email information
      $admin_email = "myEmail@example.com";
      $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
      $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
      $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];

      //send email
      mail($admin_email, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $email);

      //Email response
      echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
      }

      //if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form
      else  {
    ?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
    Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
    Subject: <input name="subject" type="text" /><br />
    Message:<br />
    <textarea name="comment" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Closing PHP**

```
<?php
  }
?>
```

**UPDATE**

I've also tried a different approach, which doesn't work either.

**contact.php**

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient="admin@example.com";
    $subject="Form to email message";
    $sender=$_POST["sender"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];

    $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\n$message";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");

    $thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Contact form to email</title>
</head>

<body>

<?=$thankYou ?>

<form method="post" action="contact.php">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input name="sender">

    <label>Email address:</label>
    <input name="senderEmail">

    <label>Message:</label>
    <textarea rows="5" cols="20" name="message"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to send header of the email, have a look at this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#108368

Comment: I concur, you need to specify the header as fully as possible to avoid the email getting junked by spam detectors.  Even then its not a given.  Also try sending it to another email address.  And look at the spam folders.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an SMTP server installed on the server you're sending the email from? Maybe that's why it's not working?

Comment: What do you mean by a SMTP server? I am running Mamp and this is rendering all of my `PHP` code.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://www.blog.tripleroi.com/2012/05/solvedenabling-sendmail-on-localhost.html) guide and see if it's any help

Comment: Thanks for the link @Alex. However, this didn't do the trick. Any other ideas?

Comment: @YoungandFree do you have postfix installed on your machine? if so, try [this](http://jonathonhill.net/2013-04-19/send-mail-using-php-on-mac-os-x/)